# Javascript validation using isNaN and !==0

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm new to javascript and I have input boxes that must not allow a zero value or non-numbers. I originaly tried to create a regular expression but I couldn't seem to get any of them to work correctly. I then came up with the following solution but it seems to only work some of the time. I think my if statements are jacked up. Any help with the code as far as making it better would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<input name="payrate" id="payrate"></td>
<input name="hours" id="hours" value="0" onclick="dollars()" onchange="dollars()"></td>
```

Javascript:

```
    function dollars(){
  var rate = 0;
  rate= document.getElementById("payrate").value;
  var hours= document.getElementById("hours").value;
  if(!isNaN(hours)){
    // !isNan - not a Number
    // !rate == 0 - value not equal to 0
    if (!isNaN(rate) && !rate == 0) {
      //round value of payrate to 2 decimal places
      var adjrate = Math.round(rate*100)/100;
      document.getElementById("payrate").value="";
      document.getElementById("payrate").value= adjrate;
      for (i=0; i<6; i++){
        document.paycheck['tax'+i].disabled = false;
      }
    }else{
      alert("You entered an invalid rate.\n"+
      "Please enter your hourly pay.\n"+
      "Example: 8.87 value entered: " + rate);
      rate = "";
      disableRadio();
      resetForm();
    }
  }else{
    alert("You entered invalid or empty hours.\n"+
    "Please enter the number of hours worked.\n"+ hours);
    hours = "";
    disableRadio();
    resetForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `!rate == 0` be `rate != 0`? `!rate` is the inverted boolean representation of `rate`. It’s never exactly equal to `0` but can be coerced to `0`. Needless to say, that’s certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check two times for isNaN. Try to simplify the conditions like this:

```
function dollars(){
  var rate = 0;
  rate= document.getElementById("payrate").value;
  var hours= document.getElementById("hours").value;
  if(!isNaN(hours)){
    // !isNan - not a Number
    // !rate == 0 - value not equal to 0
    if (rate > 0) {
      //round value of payrate to 2 decimal places
      var adjrate = Math.round(rate*100)/100;
      document.getElementById("payrate").value="";
      document.getElementById("payrate").value= adjrate;
      for (i=0; i<6; i++){
        document.paycheck['tax'+i].disabled = false;
      }
    }else{
      alert("You entered an invalid rate.\n"+
      "Please enter your hourly pay.\n"+
      "Example: 8.87 value entered: " + rate);
      rate = "";
      disableRadio();
      resetForm();
    }
  }else{
    alert("You entered invalid or empty hours.\n"+
    "Please enter the number of hours worked.\n"+ hours);
    hours = "";
    disableRadio();
    resetForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I think after staring at it for that long I just kept adding and adding making the problem compounded!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="0.01">` element. See [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp). So you will be sure that value rate and hours will be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As example - you should be able to add whatever you need in this I have commented out some of the additional function calls that were not included - but you should be able to go from here.

```
<input name="payrate" id="payrate">
<input name="hours" id="hours" value="0" onclick="dollar()" onkeyup="dollar()">

<script>
function dollar(){
  var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
  var hours= document.getElementById("hours").value;
  if(!hours || isNaN(hours)){
    alert('hours must be a numeric value greater than zeo');
   // disableRadio();
   // resetForm();
    return false; 
  }
  if (!rate || isNaN(rate)) {
    alert('rate must be a numeric value greater than zeo');
    //disableRadio();
    //resetForm();
    return false; 
  }
  var adjrate = Math.round(rate*100)/100;

  /**
   * commented out for example since not included in example code - 
  document.getElementById("payrate").value="";
  document.getElementById("payrate").value= adjrate;
  for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    document.paycheck['tax'+i].disabled = false;
  }
  */

}

</script>
```

Comment: are !rate and !hours checking to see if the values are null?

Comment: Null evaluates to false , so yes it is